# SQL script does not see database

Tags: postgresql, migration, flyway

I want to change some names in my table. I am using Flyway so I use migrations.
I want to change names in my table, but the script does not see the table. The database is dockerized.

I want to change this:

```
 create table if not exists document_entity
 (
    document_id varchar
    constraint document_entity_document_id
    not null primary key,
    document_file varchar not null
 );
```

Into this:

```
 alter table document_entity
   rename to documents;
 alter table document_entity
   rename column document_id to id;
 alter table document_entity
   rename column document_file to file;
```

I also must change relation from first table, but don't know how to write this.

Comment: Mhh, you're trying to rename `document_id` after you *already* renamed it to `id`. Of course `document_id` isn't found anymore at that point, it now is called `id`.

Comment: I did mistatke during writing post, edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have modified the table name for document_entity in the first query. The second and third query must not alter document_entity but documents because documents_entity doesn't exist any more.

```
alter table document_entity rename to documents; 
alter table documents rename column document_id to id; 
alter table documents rename column document_file to file;
```